# How to create a dialog inside onResponse method?

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, okhttp

Here is my dialog code

```
public void registrationSuccess(final Context context, String warning, String message) {
        alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        alert.setTitle(warning);
        alert.setMessage(message)
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        Intent i = new Intent(context, loginActivity.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        context.startActivity(i);
                    }
                });
        AlertDialog alertDialog = alert.create();
        alert.show();
    }
```

and I want to use it inside my onResponse method below

```
client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Failure!!");
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
            if(response.isSuccessful()) {
                registrationSuccess(getApplicationContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.congrats), getResources().getString(R.string.successfull_registration));
            } else {
                System.out.println("FAILED");

            }
        }

    });
```

getApplicationContext breaks the app with the following error showing in the console

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference
```

With what should I replace `context`?

NOTE: its non-activity class

Comment: If is it in activity class then use `ActivityName.this` and if it is non-activity class then use `getApplicationContext();`

Comment: "onResponse" method of what?

Comment: @Piyush its non activity class and using getApplicationContext() breaks the app with `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference` error on the console

Comment: Show that class

Comment: @BehrouzRiahi Then pass the context to that class.

Comment: where does this method reside? in Activity or Fragment ?

Comment: onResponse is in activity or in fragment or in service?

Comment: @Lingeshwaran in a service class

Comment: Is it in particular method?

Comment: @NJ its non-activity class

Comment: @Piyush yes it is inside onResponse method

Comment: @BehrouzRiahi in service you have any context ref at class level?

Comment: @Lingeshwaran no I don't will try create one now

Comment: @BehrouzRiahi Show that full non activity class

Comment: Pass the context to the service class and use it.

Comment: @GiacomoMasseroniChiaro Service has its own context

Comment: @BehrouzRiahi use "classname.this" and try

Comment: @Lingeshwaran it's non activity class. So `name.this` won't work!

Comment: @Kaushal28 If class extent Service then it will work I used that way.

Comment: @Lingeshwaran you mean I extend Service then I use classname.this?

Comment: @Behrouz Riahi yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From activity class, when you initialize your class, pass the context like this:

```
new My_Non_ActivityClass(MainActivity.this);
```

now in your class create a constructor like this and get context:

```
Context context;
My_Non_ActivityClass(Context c){
     context = c;
}
```

Now you have context, use wherever you want like this:

```
public void registrationSuccess(context, String warning, String message) {
    alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    alert.setTitle(warning);
    alert.setMessage(message)
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(context, loginActivity.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    context.startActivity(i);
                }
            });
    AlertDialog alertDialog = alert.create();
    alert.show();
}
```

Or no need to pass context, just access it as it is global variable in your class.

**NOTE:** If you are in service, the service has its own context. Just use `this`.

Comment: Service is a Context, so Context context = this; do it at constructor and pass to that method too.

Answer (score 0):

Create getter setter methods in Application class  for context then 
with this use can get context across the application

change this line

```
registrationSuccess(null, getResources().getString(R.string.congrats), getResources().getString(R.string.successfull_registration));
```

With this

```
registrationSuccess(ApplicationControler.getContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.congrats), getResources().getString(R.string.successfull_registration));
```

Comment: you mean modifying Application class? how can I access it? I am new to android